# How to run Windows shell commands from Lisp with asdf uiop:run-program under sbcl

Tags: windows, shell, common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

We would like to invoke Windows shell commands from within Lisp, using sbcl and asdf `uiop:run-program`.

What we have done under emacs/slime on Windows 10 using sbcl 1.3.6. 64 bit and asdf 3.1.5. is:

```
CL-USER>(require 'asdf)
(shadowing-import 'asdf::run-program)
```

Then, what works correctly (as on Unix) is this:

```
CL-USER>(run-program "echo test" :output :string)
"test
"
NIL
0
CL-USER>
```

But what does not work at all and errors out are any operations with files:

```
(run-program "dir")

(run-program "copy foo.txt tmp")

(run-program "xcopy *.texi tmp")
```

with or without `:output :string` as argument. We are not sure whether we do something wrong, or whether there is a bug related to sbcl or to asdf, or whether this functionality is still supported by asdf and sbcl for windows 10 at all. Comparable shell commands seem to work well on Unix.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Support for run-program on sbcl on Windows was significantly improved in the last few months, notably thanks to the efforts of Elias Pipping, plus lots of testing and bug fixing by Robert Goldman and me.

Grab the latest SBCL 1.3.15 and the latest ASDF 3.2.0 (or even 3.2.0.2 from the "test" branch), and it should work much better.

Comment: Indeed, with sbcl 1.3.15 and asdf 3.2.0 it works much better. Xcopy and copy work with wildcards. Md and rd work. Del unfortunately works only for individual files in the present directory, no for wildcards (which is a pity, because that's what we need) and not for files given with a path. Dir still errors out. Chdir has no effect, we have to set *default-pathname-defaults* manually. But that's an amazing progress, nevertheless. Thank you all very much.

Comment: Does uiop:delete-directory-tree and friends help?

Comment: `uiop:chdir` and binding `*default-pathname-defaults*` are complementary, not overlapping changes.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but my understanding is that delete-directory-tree deletes the directory with everything in it. But in Windows I can do del *.texi to delete 100 texi files out of a total of 500 files. How do I do this with uiop?

Comment: Concerning chdir, this is at least not the expected behavior from the Windows shell command (I'm not speaking about uiop:chdir, but about (uiop:run-program "chdir ...")).

Comment: Oh, to delete just the *.texi, you can try `(map () 'delete-file-if-exists (directory* "*.texi")`

Comment: `uiop:run-program` has a `:directory` keyword argument.

Comment: Each run-program starts a new process; if you use chdir in one it won't work in the other. The command to change the directory within a shell is cd ${foo} and the command separator is ; on Unix and & in Windows.

Comment: This delete *.texi works perfectly. So I see there is much more for me to discover in uiop. Thanks a lot!